# How to merge TFS changeset from branch A to branch C. Branch A was merged into branch B and there's no merge realationship between A and C

Tags: visual-studio-2015, tfs, merge, branch

Given there are 3 TFS branches - A, B and C.
You can merge changesets from A into B and from B into C. But can't merge changes from A into C.
A -> B -> C.
There are some my changesets in branch A I need to merge into branch C.
All the changesets(from all the users) were already merged from A to B.

When I try to merge from B to C it doesn't provide a list of my change sets from A (just one big changeset having all the changes for some period.)
When I try to merge my particular change sets from A to B I can't see them either because they are already part of branch B.

Is there a smart way to merge my selected changes from A or B into C and not to break any future merges.

Thanks.

Comment: Hi vadim, any update on this?

Comment: I just performed baseless merge. Not all the lines were merged correctly without showing conflicts. It's tricky especially if you still can build the code but some fixes aren't there anymore. Hopefully I've updated files with unexpected merge result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's  impossible to achieve A -> B -> C merge and keep all history. Branching/move will **lost the folder history** , but the individual file history is actually not lost. It is hidden under the little "expand me" arrow at the far left on a file history line. Expand it on the oldest history entry for a file, or anywhere you see it, and you will see history of that individual file also from an old location that no longer exists.

However, as you can see, merge the branch of changeset is **based on the folder history.** Such as the first changeset of `Branch B` will be changeset XXX branched from   `BranchA`.

You will not be able to select the older changeset of  `BranchA`

---

**Solution**

A way to achieve what your need is directly merge `BranchA` with old changeset to `Branch C`  Even though you will get a warning prompt as below:

> A merge relationship does not exist between the source and the target.
>   A **baseless merge will be performed**.

You need to [do a baseless merge](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/tfvc/merge-command?view=vsts) the target branch in cmd.

`tf merge /baseless <<source path>> <<target path>> /recursive`

Answer (score 1):

What you're describing is called a baseless merge. Although you can perform them, doing so is not recommended, and is almost always indicative that you have a problem with your branching strategy.

You can perform a baseless merge with the `tf` command line tool. I do not believe it's possible within the Visual Studio IDE, although I could be wrong as it's been a number of years since I've had to perform a baseless merge.

I would strongly recommend evaluating what happened in your workflow that got you in a situation where you need to perform a baseless merge. It could be that your branching strategy is inadequate, or it could be that your workflow would be better suited to another VCS, such as Git.